# How to check if service-worker exist in given URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, service-worker

Can I distinguish given external web sites have 'service-worker' or not?

My best guess is:

1. retrieve all the js files from given URL
2. search for string 'sw.js'

(i am unsure how to do this as well)

Given data would be like this:

```
const sitesToCheck = {
    'www.site1.com',
    'www.site2.com',
    'www.site3.com',
}
```

Comment: URL on a server you own or any external server?

Comment: On webpage, You can check under `Application Pannel > Service Workers` under `Chrome Developer Tools`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by [Nicolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717195/nicolas-hoizey), this check can be done using headless Chrome.

Below is an example using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer):

```
'use strict'

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {

  try {
    // Step 1: launch browser and open a new page.
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    // Step 2: Go to a URL and wait for a service worker to register.
    var url = 'https://web.dev/'
    await page.goto(url)
    const swTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(target => target.type() === 'service_worker')

    // Step 3a: If a service worker is registered, print URL of SW file to the console 
    if(swTarget) {
      console.log(swTarget._targetInfo['url'])
    }
    // Step 4: Done. Close.
    await browser.close()

  } catch (err) {
    // The process will timeout after 30s, if no service worker is registered
    console.error(err.message)
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 26):

If you want to do this in code, you can only do it within the same origin as the worker(s) you want to check for. Within the same origin, you can use [`getRegistration(url)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/#service-worker-container-getregistration-method) (which gives you a promise that will be fulfilled with `undefined` or a [`ServiceWorkerRegistration` object](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/#service-worker-registration-interface) for the URL, or which is rejected if the URL is invalid), or [`getRegistrations()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/#service-worker-container-getregistrations-method) (which gives you a promise for an array of [`ServiceWorkerRegistration` objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers-1/#service-worker-registration-interface)). E.g.:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(registrations => {
    console.log(registrations);
});
```

Comment: If it's NOT from the same origin, what else I can try?

Comment: @RNA: As far as I know, nothing, in a web browser; this stuff is restricted to the same origin for a reason. **Not** from a browser, you could download all of the site's JavaScript and check for calls to `navigator.serviceWorker.register` (this requires a *lot* of analysis, handling things like `const sw = navigator.serviceWorker; sw.register(...);`, or `const foo = "ister"; navigator["ser" + "vice" + "Work" + "er"]["reg" + foo](...);`).

Comment: In my case (Chrome 90), I see that when the `registrations` object is wrapped in an array. If service worker is not active for the present URL, the array is empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at [Service Worker Detector](https://github.com/google/service-worker-detector), a Chrome extension that detects if a website registers a Service Worker by reading the `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` property. It might also work in [other browsers supporting Web Extensions](https://github.com/google/service-worker-detector/commit/fd2971d7e0bc3b9fa136404854126c25b8ce411f), but it looks like it is not yet distributed as such.

However, it requires the script to be run in a browser, which might not cover your needs. You can try with a scriptable [headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).

Comment: thanks for the clue, i found a tool called `lighthouse`(https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/) I'll try to get it working in my code :)

Comment: Lighthouse is indeed currently the best tool to test webapps for web development best practices, including performance and PWA.

Comment: is `navigator.serviceWorker.controller` reliable way to check if service worker exists or not?